# Getting "Cannot create a row of size ..." Error After a Power Failure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

After a power failure one of our stored procedures (which inserts data from a DB to another DB with some changes) started to give this error:

> Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Cannot create a row of size 8067 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

My data is nowhere close to the mentioned size and the SP was working fine prior to the power failure.

Our only solution to it is to recreate the destination table and move the old data to the new one.
But since this issue has happened to us several times, I decided to ask why it happens and if there is any better solution?

I've already tried the following actions but to no avail:

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE 
DBCC CHECKTABLE WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS
DBCC CHECKDB
rebuilding the index
```

Table Definition:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Requests](
    [Autokey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RequesterName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CustomerId] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [DateReq] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [TimeReq] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [Registrar] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
    [Subject] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [ChkApproveRR] [bit] NULL,
    [RemRR] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Remwork] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ContractId] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [FlagArchive] [char](1) NULL,
    [InvoiceNo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [SerialAcc] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [FiscalPeriod] [smallint] NULL,
    [DateFinish] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [CustRequestNo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [IsAdvance] [bit] NULL,
    [DlvDeviceKey] [bigint] NULL,
    [WebRequestNo] [bigint] NULL,
    [WebRequestAutoKey] [bigint] NULL,
    [Uploaded] [bit] NULL,
    [ChkApproveWork] [bit] NULL,
    [ScanPath] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [computer] [bit] NULL,
    [Tracker] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Requests] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Autokey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Requests] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__RequestUpload]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Uploaded]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Requests] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__RequestsChkApp]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ChkApproveWork]
GO
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_AddRequestUsingCustomerServiceRequestInAutomation] @JobId nvarchar(50), @JobNo bigint
AS 

DECLARE @StrSql nvarchar(4000)

BEGIN
        
        If Not Exists(Select * From [IPAddress].[DBMK].dbo.sysColumns Where name = 'ServiceRequestNoTemp' 
        And id = (Select t.object_id From [IPAddress].[DBMK].sys.tables As t Where t.[name] = PARSENAME('[IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]', 1)))
            EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] ADD [ServiceRequestNoTemp] nvarchar(50)') AT [IPAddress]

        If Not Exists(Select * From [IPAddress].[DBMK].dbo.sysColumns Where name = 'CustomerAccDetailTemp' 
        And id = (Select t.object_id From [IPAddress].[DBMK].sys.tables As t Where t.[name] = PARSENAME('[IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]', 1)))
            EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] ADD CustomerAccDetailTemp nvarchar(50)')  AT [IPAddress]

        If Not Exists(Select * From [IPAddress].[DBMK].dbo.sysColumns Where name = 'ItemDescriptionTemp' 
        And id = (Select t.object_id From [IPAddress].[DBMK].sys.tables As t Where t.[name] = PARSENAME('[IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]', 1)))
            EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] ADD ItemDescriptionTemp nvarchar(255)')  AT [IPAddress]
            
        If Not Exists(Select * From [IPAddress].[DBMK].dbo.sysColumns Where name = 'SerialTemp' 
        And id = (Select t.object_id From [IPAddress].[DBMK].sys.tables As t Where t.[name] = PARSENAME('[IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]', 1)))
            EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] ADD SerialTemp nvarchar(200)')  AT [IPAddress]

        SET @StrSql='INSERT INTO [IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests](WebRequestNo,RequesterName,Description,Registrar,ServiceRequestNoTemp,CustomerAccDetailTemp,ItemDescriptionTemp,SerialTemp)
        SELECT '''+ CAST(@JobNo AS varchar(50)) +''',LEFT(s.Applicant,50),LEFT(s.Description,100),CASE WHEN ISNULL(rUser.LastName,'''')>'''' THEN LEFT(rUser.LastName,30) ELSE LEFT(lUser.LegalName,30) END AS Registar
        ,  CAST(j.JobNo AS varchar(50)) ,p.AccDetailsId ,LEFT(s.ItemDescription,255),s.Serial
        FROM [DBSource].dbo.CustomerServiceRequests s
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.Jobs j ON s.Id = j.SourceId
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.Positions pos ON pos.Id=s.RequesterPositionId
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.People p ON pos.PersonId =p.Id
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.PersonReals r ON p.PersonRealId=r.Id 
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.Positions posUser ON posUser.Id=s.RequesterPositionId
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.People pUser ON posUser.PersonId =pUser.Id
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.PersonReals rUser ON pUser.PersonRealId=rUser.Id  
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.PersonLegals lUser ON pUser.PersonLegalId =lUser.Id 
        WHERE j.Id=''' + @JobId + ''''
        print (@StrSql)
        EXEC (@StrSql) 

        SET @StrSql='Update [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]
        SET DateReq= [DBMK].[dbo].[NumericFullDate] (GETDATE()) , TimeReq=REPLACE(LEFT((convert(time(0), GETDATE ())),5) ,'':'','''')
        ,CustomerId=(SELECT ISNULL(c.CustId,'''') FROM [DBMK].[dbo].[AccDetails] a
        LEFT JOIN [DBMK].[dbo].[Customers] c ON a.DetailCode  =c.DetailCode  
        LEFT JOIN [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] r ON r.CustomerAccDetailTemp=a.GUID
        WHERE r.ServiceRequestNoTemp='''+ CAST(@JobNo AS varchar(50)) +''')
        WHERE ServiceRequestNoTemp='''+ CAST(@JobNo AS varchar(50)) +''''
        print (@StrSql)
        EXEC (@StrSql) AT [IPAddress]

        SET @StrSql='INSERT INTO [IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Activitys](RequestedNumber ,ActivityCode ,CustomerId , Description,SoftwareID )
        SELECT r.Autokey,''10'',r.CustomerId,rs.Description +'' ''+IsNull(rs.ExtraDescription,'''')+'' ''+''Path ''+IsNull(rs.InstallationLocation,'''')+'' ''+ CASE WHEN ISNULL(r.SerialTemp,'''')>'''' THEN '' ('' + r.SerialTemp +'')'' ELSE '''' END ,s.SysId 
        FROM [IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] r
        LEFT JOIN [IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Systems] s ON r.ItemDescriptionTemp=s.description 
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.Jobs j ON j.JobNo=r.ServiceRequestNoTemp
        LEFT JOIN [DBSource].dbo.CustomerServiceRequests rs ON rs.Id = j.SourceId
        WHERE r.ServiceRequestNoTemp='''+ CAST(@JobNo AS varchar(50)) +''''
        print (@StrSql)
        EXEC (@StrSql)-- AT [IPAddress]
END

If Exists(Select * From [IPAddress].[DBMK].dbo.sysColumns Where name = 'ServiceRequestNoTemp' 
And id = (Select t.object_id From [IPAddress].[DBMK].sys.tables As t Where t.[name] = PARSENAME('[IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]', 1)))
    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] DROP COLUMN ServiceRequestNoTemp')AT [IPAddress]     

If Exists(Select * From [IPAddress].[DBMK].dbo.sysColumns Where name = 'CustomerAccDetailTemp' 
And id = (Select t.object_id From [IPAddress].[DBMK].sys.tables As t Where t.[name] = PARSENAME('[IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]', 1)))
    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] DROP COLUMN CustomerAccDetailTemp') AT [IPAddress]           

If Exists(Select * From [IPAddress].[DBMK].dbo.sysColumns Where name = 'ItemDescriptionTemp' 
And id = (Select t.object_id From [IPAddress].[DBMK].sys.tables As t Where t.[name] = PARSENAME('[IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]', 1)))
    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] DROP COLUMN ItemDescriptionTemp')     AT [IPAddress]

If Exists(Select * From [IPAddress].[DBMK].dbo.sysColumns Where name = 'SerialTemp' 
And id = (Select t.object_id From [IPAddress].[DBMK].sys.tables As t Where t.[name] = PARSENAME('[IPAddress].[DBMK].[dbo].[Requests]', 1)))
    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE [DBMK].[dbo].[Requests] DROP COLUMN SerialTemp') AT [IPAddress]  
GO
```

The error happens at the first INSERT.

Please note the SP works fine under normal circumstances and this only happens after power failures.

Comment: What sql server version are you running? Perhaps time to get a power generator. Also, please post the query and table definition

Comment: You're probably better off actually investigating the error, I suspect the power cut is a red-herring. Something isn't right with the database if that error can happen. Track it down.

Comment: I agree, it's almost certain this has nothing to do with the outage (especially if DBCC didn't turn up anything). Take a look at computed columns and triggers, and double-check your assumption about what data is being inserted. Note that an `UPDATE` can cause this as well as an `INSERT`.

Comment: If recreating the table fixes it... does your table include any of the deprecated `image`, `ntext` or `text` columns? Does someone later execute `sp_tableoption <yourTableNameHere>, 'text in row', <someNumberBetween24and7000>`?

Comment: @siggemannen SQL Server 15, We already have a UPS but it failed a few times. I'll update the post with the query and the table script.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No it doesn't.

Comment: There is no sql server 15. Run `select @@version`

Comment: @siggemannen 15.0.2000.5

Comment: Dude, that's the version of management studio I think

Comment: @siggemannen  `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor) `

Comment: Having a stored proc that adds columns to a table, does some work, and then drops them is a very bad idea. You will be seeing this error due to the cumulative space taken up by the dropped columns across multiple executions

Comment: @MartinSmith Doesn't `DBCC CLEANTABLE` fix it?

Comment: Have you also done similar with a fixed length column? "The command doesn't reclaim space after a fixed-length column is dropped" Anyway you can use the query in "Inspecting the physical table structure" to check this https://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry, I didn't know this.